# C Socket Reading TOO MUCH Data

Tags: c, sockets

I am making a server that should be able to accept requests from multiple clients.  To ensure I am reading large requests properly, I made the below code segment.

Requests come in the form `<START_REQUEST>a long message<END_REQUEST>`

```
read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
// Keep Reading If Entire Message Not Recieved
int buffer_len = strlen(buffer);
char *end_tag = &buffer[buffer_len-strlen("<END_REQUEST>")];
while(strcmp(end_tag, "<END_REQUEST>") != 0) {

    char *temp_buffer;
    temp_buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);

    valread = read(fd, temp_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    strcat(buffer, temp_buffer);

    free(temp_buffer);

    buffer_len = strlen(buffer);
    end_tag = &buffer[buffer_len-strlen("<END_REQUEST>")];
}
```

However, sometimes (very often) the contents of buffer are something like:
`<START_REQUEST>a long message<END_REQUEST>somegarbagedataheremaybefromanotherequest?`
and thus the loop never terminates.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: `read()` reads binary data, meaning it doesn't end the buffer with `\0` to make it safe to use with `strcat()`. Also why are you allocating the buffer only to free it again at every freaking loop? Do it only once.

Comment: @Havenard Or, better yet, just read the data into wherever you want it in the first place. There's no point in reading it somewhere other than where you want it just to have to copy it to where you wanted it in the first place.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Indeed, using an intermediate buffer makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

How are you expecting `strcat` to know how many bytes to append onto the buffer?

```
valread = read(fd, temp_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
strcat(buffer, temp_buffer);
```

After the call to `read`, `valread` holds the number of bytes you read and it's the only thing that holds this information. However, you attempt to append data read onto the existing buffer without using this value -- so there is no possible way `strcat` could conceivably know how many bytes to append onto the buffer. It's no wonder you append junk that you read before.

Similar problem here:

```
read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
// Keep Reading If Entire Message Not Recieved
int buffer_len = strlen(buffer);
```

Here you ignore the return value of `read`, so you have no way to know how many bytes you read. How are you expecting `strlen` to figure out how many bytes `read` put into the buffer?